# C# set directory permission in SAMBA share

Tags: c#, .net, samba

I am making a small program to create directories on samba network share and I am having a big problem with setting permissions to created directories.
I have to create directory on remote network share and assign permissions for active directory users.

Code that I am using to set permissions:

```
    public void SetPermission(string domain, string adminUser, string setUser, string pass, string path)
    {
        using (var impersonation = new Impersonation(domain, adminUser, pass))
        {
            var directory = !Directory.Exists(path) ? Directory.CreateDirectory(path) : new DirectoryInfo(path);
            var directorySecurity = directory.GetAccessControl();
            directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule($"{domain}\\{setUser}", FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow));
            directory.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);
        }
    }
```

Always on directory.SetAccessControl() I get:

- error: "method failed with unexpected error 50"
- stack trace:

  - at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
  - at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
  - at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.Persist(String fullPath)

I was looking for a solution for many hours and tried a lot of combinations too, but I did not find the answer to what the error 50 is and solution to set permissions. My question is: it is possible to grant these rights?

Comment: Looking at the .NET code in ILSpy, it looks like it makes a call to the Windows function SetSecurityInfo. If the function fails, it returns a nonzero error code defined in WinError.h.  Looking up error 50, the message means "The request is not supported.".  Are you able to manually set the security to the same configuration remotely?

Comment: Hi, problem is that I don't see any security option on directory but via powershell or cmd I can give permissons. Also the admin of the client told me that everything should work and give me all rights to create directories and change permissions.

Comment: For comparison to the C# code, what powershell or cmd are you using that is working correctly.